# How to Convert Existing COM and VSTO Add-ins for the New Outlook on Windows

Tags: vsto, outlook-web-addins, comaddin, new-outlook

This includes three initial questions regarding moving from existing COM, VSTO, and stand-alone EXE apps to the New Outlook on Windows web add-in environment.

I have three primary questions to start with:

1. With the New Outlook on Windows, will standalone exe's be able to instantiate an Outlook application object and continue to use all the properties and methods they currently can use?
2. Some current COM and VSTO add-ins utilize complex Windows form dialogs for user interaction. How is this even remotely possible with the narrow web add-in task pane required by the New Outlook on Windows? Seems almost an impossible change to make.
3. Is the Outlook javascript object model anywhere near as fully capable as the current object model for COM and VSTO add-ins? If not, how can any company with existing COM and VSTO add-ins even consider using the New Outlook on Windows?

Thank you for any ideas on this.

I have built web add-ins that work with the pane, javascript, and backend C#. However, these apps are much different and far more limited than current COM and VSTO add-ins that work in Outlook 2016 and 365.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all 3 is "not yet". Keep in mind that desktop Outlook is fully supported - Microsoft realizes that there are tens of thousands of LOB apps and COM addins that many companies rely on. The desktop version of Outlook is not being replaced - it is still a part of the Office suit.

The new Outlook (Monarch) is a replacement for Windows Mail and Windows Calendar, not the desktop version of Outlook.

Comment: Hi Dmitry. Thank you for responding. The thing that concerns me is that I'm reading things that suggest Microsoft may not support Classic Outlook on Windows beyond 2026. It seems to me that converting existing COM and VSTO addins for many companies in 3 years time would be a very difficult task.

Comment: IMHO, Microsoft is not Google - that would contradict everything that they've done in the past 30 years. They don't leave customers high and dry. The way I read it, they do want to consolidate their codebase by having a single multi-platform version of Outlook (that's a great idea on the PM level, not sure about dev), but they want to do it by making the new Outlook more attractive on the corp level and switch only after the portion of the desktop users becomes tiny and the switch becomes painless.

Comment: They are not there yet, and I am not at all convinced they will be there in 2026. From my own experience in the past 25 years, we have at least another decade.

Comment: Here's a very recent article that lays out Microsoft's supposed rollout plan: https://redmondmag.com/articles/2023/09/12/new-outlook-for-windows.aspx

Even if they do continue support for Classic longer than a few years, they will probably put new features and updates into the New Outlook only and that will make companies want to move over to New Outlook rather than stay on Classic. So there will probably be a push to move all the COM and VSTO stuff over to web add-ins. But, as you said, I don't think web add-ins can possibly match the functionality of COM/VSTO.

Comment: I have seen that presentation, but without going into NDA details, they are only more or less specific about Windows Mail and Windows Calendar. As the article itself points out, classic Outlook is "~1 + Years"

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Ultimately, I don't think they can remove support for COM and VSTO. I think they need to keep that. I enjoy writing the web apps, but they just can't do all the same things... yet. But really javascript running in what amounts to a web page isn't ever going to be as capable as COM/VSTO.